# Create a matrix form a list

Tags: r

I'm wondering if there's a way to create a `nx2 matrix` from this list:

```
a =

:chr [1, 1] "4"

:chr [1, 1] "2"

:chr [1, 1] "3" "4"

:chr [1, 1] "4"

:chr [1, 1] "5"

:chr [1, 1] "4" "6"

:chr [1, 1] "4"
```

For final result I want a nx2 matrix with NA values where needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A convenient way is to use `stri_list2matrix` from the "stringi" package.

Example:

```
> L <- list(4, 2:3, 3, 1, 1:2)
> library(stringi)
> stri_list2matrix(L, byrow = TRUE)
     [,1] [,2]
[1,] "4"  NA  
[2,] "2"  "3" 
[3,] "3"  NA  
[4,] "1"  NA  
[5,] "1"  "2"
```

In base R, you can write a function like the following to get you started:

```
listFlatten <- function(inlist, type = "numeric") {
  len <- max(lengths(inlist))
  t(vapply(inlist, function(x) `length<-`(x, len), vector(mode = type, len)))
}

## Try it out....
listFlatten(L)
```